# Automation Error when using ADO/MDAC

Tags: database, vb6, mdac

OK, struggling to get a definitive answer to this one...

I have an application written in VB6 which requires MDAC (2.8 for this installation). MDAC is included in the installer for my application. When the software is removed and re-installed on the same machine MDAC seems to go awry and I receive the following error as soon as my application tries to connect to the database:

Run-time error '-2147024769 (8007007f)':

Automation error
The specified procedure could not be found.

I have tried reinstalling MDAC which completes successfully, but does not fix the problem. I have searched over much of the Internet and found many people with a similar problem in different environments (VS.NET, JAVA etc), in fact anything that relies on MDAC, but cannot find a clear answer. Anyone who has a clean solution would receive my most merrily given thanks and appreciation.

Yours in bated anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [MDAC Component Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307255) from Microsoft? It is a tool for diagnosing problems and reconfiguring MDAC installations.

Comment: Thanks Mitch Following your suggestion have just run the MDAC Component Checker. There are some mismatched files and mismatched registry entries. I shall try changing all the registry entries first and see what happens. I guess I may be able to download the correct file versions from somewhere?

Comment: I would completely remove MDAC and then re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I have found removing MDAC 2.8 to be all but impossible. However, having run the component checker, changing the registry entries and putting a different version of MSDART the problem has been fixed.

The MSDART I have put in place is not the one suggested by the component checker, but it works. The component checker also has a problem with the version of MSXML, but the software seems to work regardless, so I'll look into this at a later date. However my problem is solved. So very quickly. Thanks and praises to you Mitch, and Stackoverflow. Great!