# VBA / VB6 - ADO Error 8007007e. Goes away on reboot - but then returns for all projects

Tags: vba, vb6, ado

The error text is: "Run-time error '-2147024770 (8007007e)'. Automation error. The specified module could not be found."

I'm running Win7-64 Pro

In all my affected projects I'm referencing the MS ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Libraries (it doesn't seem to matter which one is referenced - for the purposes of troubleshooting this error).

What is frustrating is that if I reboot the PC the error goes away - for awhile. After rebooting and more debugging (various projects: VB6 & VBA), the error will return.

```
Dim pcnFADB_SQL As ADODB.Connection

'The error is thrown on the following code
Set pcnFADB_SQL = New ADODB.Connection
```

I don't have this issue if I run the projects on my Win7-32 Pro PC.

- not a dup as this issue is intermittant

Comment: What is the *text* of the error ?  Is your VBA host (Excel or ?) 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Sorry - my full response: The error text is: "Run-time error '-2147024770 (8007007e)'. Automation error. The specified module could not be found." Both my VBA (Office 2010 Pro) & VB6 are 32-bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automation Error when using ADO/MDAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283793/automation-error-when-using-ado-mdac)